# programmatically assigning imageurl not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set up my iis6 so that the images are inside of a virtual folder

if i assign the imageurl in the .aspx it works:

example.aspx

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/labelimages/0603142_1.jpg" />
```

there are 2 more images, when i try to assign the imageurl via codebehind to them it won't work;

example.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image2.ImageUrl = "~/labelimages/0603142_1.jpg";
        Image3.ImageUrl = @"~/labelimages/0603142_1.jpg";
    }
```

when i test this in visual Studio it displays a placeholder Image, the links are processed correctly, source:

```
<img id="contentMaster_ContentSub_Image1" src="labelimages/0603142_1.jpg" />
<img id="contentMaster_ContentSub_Image2" src="labelimages/0603142_1.jpg" />
<img id="contentMaster_ContentSub_Image3" src="labelimages/0603142_1.jpg" />
```

then i copy this to the server and it displays only the hardcoded picture, looking into the source:

```
<img id="contentMaster_ContentSub_Image1" src="labelimages/0603142_1.jpg" />
<img id="contentMaster_ContentSub_Image2" src="imageurl" />
<img id="contentMaster_ContentSub_Image3" src="imageurl" />
```

not only the images aren't working, any not hardcoded links are weird.
why isn't it working?

Comment: I think there is no issue with your code. Are you sure you are looking at the latest compiled version?

Comment: *Head and table meet with some force* yes, that was the Problem, thank you!

Comment: Both :D btw, pls make a post, so that i can set this as answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no issue with your code. Are you sure you are looking at the latest compiled version?

You should try to cleanup first, then recompile.